# Composer installation -sS or -s

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

On the webiste of Composer we can see this command :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

What is the option -sS ?

Because i also see this solution on another tutorial :

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you want to do. From [the curl manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) we can see that `-s` means "silent mode":

> -s, --silent
>
> Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

and that `-S` means to show errors:

> -S, --show-error
>
> When used with -s it makes curl show an error message if it fails.

Personally, I would use `-sS`.

Comment: The reason is that we only had -s originally so a lot of tutorials picked it up, and were not updated to the newer/better -sS unfortunately.